# Merge Two collection into one in mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have **two** collections "A" and "B" and I want to **merge** the objects in "B" into "A" using **aggregate**, **lookup** in MongoDB

For example,
I have

```
 CollectionA: [
    {"_id":1, "amount":1500}, 
    {"_id":2, "amount":500}
    ]
```

, and

```
CollectionB: [
{"_id":1, "amount":400, "name":A}, 
{"_id":2, "amount":500, "name":B}
]
```

**EXPECTED ANSWER LIKE THIS,**

```
 FinalCollection: [
    {"_id":1, "amount": 1500}, 
    {"_id":2, "amount":500}, 
    {"_id":3, "amount":400, "name":A}, 
    {"_id":4, "amount":500, "name":B}
    ]
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is a "straight" merge, yes?   Simply copying the docs from collection B into collection A and assigning new `_id`?   Any special handling of `_id` required?    Can we just let the driver invent the new `_id`?

Comment: Actually I am working with ReactJS, GraphQL, and MongoDB so I want to merge objects of collection B into A using aggregate  @BuzzMoschetti